# Trying to get Spring Batch Hello World 3 Sample running

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I been trying to get the Spring Batch Hello World 3 example running from

http://jroller.com/0xcafebabe/entry/spring_batch_hello_world_3

But I keep getting the following errors.  Can someone please try to help me out

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao#1f25fefa' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao#1f25fefa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:190)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:254)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao#1f25fefa' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao#1f25fefa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao#1f25fefa' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao.<clinit>(MapJobInstanceDao.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: If you are using Spring 3.1 jar and default aop.jar then sometimes you also get this kind of errors. You can get it solved using : <a href="http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.in/2012/09/spring-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html">Spring AOP Issue</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [aopalliance.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar) to your CLASSPATH. Also see this [thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82282).

Comment: thanks but now I get this error: SEVERE: Job Terminated in error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor

Comment: This is a different problem, we need to see your XML configuration of `jobRepository` as well as the version of Spring Batch you use. But please mark this question as answered and **open a new one**.